# How to capture logs in django rest framework to database not using any library?

Tags: python-3.x, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I want to capture my logs in the program, which include INFO, DEBUG, WARN, EXCEPTION to the database. without using any django libraries. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear.

If you want to aggregate your logs in a database, you have to define a new Logging handler, give a look to [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler).

*Note : I would suggest Sentry as it has free plan and allow you to get all errors in one application*